# Do we need to use a synchronized block for Room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, synchronized, android-multithreading

I have some code that I would like to use something like a threadpool because I am making multiple transactions at once.  I used to use a SQLite database with a synchronized block.  I figure that Room handles multi-threaded behaviour for you.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

> I figure that Room handles multi-threaded behaviour for you. Is that correct?

No it does not.

- Room is a wrapper around SQLite, it does, by default, not allow you to use the main thread *(using `.allowMainThreadQueires` when building the database allows the restriction to be circumvented)*. The end result is still an SQLite database according to the SQLite version the resultant device is shipped with/has installed.
- Room does implement some additions, such as the room_master_table (which stores a hashed value that is compared at run time against the compiled hash to detect if changes have been made (the hash is a hash of the schema, that Room generates according to the `@Entity` annotated classes defined to the `@Database` annotation)).